# Why is Dirac Delta function necessary?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, wavefunction, dirac-delta-distributions, quantum-measurements

I know this is a stupid question, but I have serious trouble understanding it.
The position operator ${\hat X}$ on ${\cal H} \equiv L^2(a, b)$, defined as
$$\hat X \psi = x \psi$$

is linear, bounded and self-adjoint.

> **Postulate**. The result of measuring a physical quantity ${\displaystyle {\mathcal {A}}}$ must be one of the eigenvalues of the corresponding observable ${\displaystyle A}$.

In this case, considering a "concrete" scenario, I have a particle in a (one-dimensional) box of side $l = |a-b|$, so I expect to find it in the generic position $\lambda \in (a, b)$. The issue is solving
$ x\psi = \lambda \psi$ for some $\psi \in \cal H$.

**Why can't simply be $x=\lambda$?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The operator $\hat X$ acts on a wavefunction $\psi \in L^2(a,b)$ giving us another function $\hat X \psi \in L^2(a,b)$ defined by:
$$\forall x\in (a,b), (\hat X\psi)(x) = x\psi(x)$$

When you are trying to solve the eigenvalue problem $\hat X \psi = \lambda \psi$, what you are asking is:
$$\forall x\in(a,b), x\psi(x) = \lambda\psi(x)\hspace{2cm}(*)$$
This implies:
$$\forall x\in(a,b), (x-\lambda)\psi(x) = 0$$
Therefore, $\psi(x) = 0$ when $x\neq \lambda$. This mean that we do not have a solution in $L^2(a,b)$, but a generalized solution, given by:
$$\psi(x) = \delta(x-\lambda)$$
which you can check does satisfy $(*)$.